# How to delete data from mongodb v3.4 with hibernate ogm 5.1.0?

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate-ogm

I am only able to retrieve data and insert data in mongo DB v 3.4 using Hibernate OGM 5.1.0.Final. I am not able to perform delete operation or update operations. Can anyone help me out with an example?

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit vague, I'm not sure if you know how to delete an entity with Hibernate OGM and it's not working (in this case post an example of your code, please) or you don't know how JPA works. I will assume you don't know how to delete entities and add some examples on how to do it.

Using the session:

```
try ( Session session = openSession() ) {
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    Hypothesis entity = (Hypothesis) session.get( Hypothesis.class, hyp.getId() );
    session.delete( entity );
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Using the EntityManager (JPA):

```
final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
try {
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  Poem poem = em.find( Poem.class, poem.getId() );
  em.remove( poem );
  em.getTransaction().commit();
}
finally {
  em.close();
}
```

Using the MonogDB CLI API:

```
try ( OgmSession session = openSession() ) {
  Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
  String nativeQuery = "db.Poem.remove({ '_id': { '$numberLong': '11' } })";
  Query query = session.createNativeQuery( nativeQuery ).addEntity( Poem.class );
  query.executeUpdate();
}
```

About updates, I will leave it to the [Hibernate ORM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-managed-state).
If this doesn't answer your question please, try to elaborate more. Test cases are always appreciated.